# VBA for If Z value exists, hide the following: that row, X rows before, and Y rows after

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering if someone could kindly help me with this problem.

If a cell contains value Z, I want to hide that row, X rows before, and Y rows after.

I've tried something like this but there are some cases where it doesn't work:

```
Dim r = long
For r = 1  To 100 Step 7
    Rows(r & ":" r + 6).Hidden = Cells(r, "B").Value = "not included"
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ThtJeP3.png]

So, via the example above, for the range B1:B15, if a cell contains "#n/a" then hide row 14, rows 10:13, and row 15 (the highlighted rows). I want this to loop, where either we have it check every cell in B1:B15, or for it to check every nth cell, where n = 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so, what is not working?

Comment: So what is it? A `#N/A` worksheet error returned from a formula or the test string `"not included"`? That's a pretty wide variation.

Comment: @Jeeped where'd your comment go?

Answer (score 3):

try the following code

```
Dim LastRow As Long

Public Sub Program()
    FindingLastRow

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If IsError(Cells(i, "B").Value) Then
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
                Rows(i - 4 & ":" & i + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                i = i + 2
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print LastRow
End Sub

Sub FindingLastRow()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any ideas why, despite pasting the code exactly as shown, I get a type 13 error for this line?

`Rows(i - 4 & ":" & i + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: What is the value of `i` when you get this error? Maybe its trying to hide row <=0

Comment: Zsmaster, it does for me now too...see below
@Sphinx, yep that was the issue now that I look at it again :P
I'll comment back in the morning with how this solution is working. Fatigue + VBA noob = bad.